# Alternative to djvubind which supports colors

Tags: djvu

Is there an alternative to [djvubind](https://code.google.com/p/djvubind/), which supports colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[didjvu](http://code.google.com/p/didjvu/) seems to be interesting. For ocr one can use orcodjvu in a second step.

Answer (score 0):

`djvubind` supports mixed mode `tiff` images. So if you use for example `scantailor` to produce mixed mode tiffs (where the image parts can be in color), `djvubind` automatically produces a djvu, where the colors are preserved.